# PHP fwrite creates empty files without file extension?

Tags: php, fwrite

I wrote a little PHP snippet which is mainly supposed to read and write .txt files. Anyhow PHP fwrite creates empty files without file extension. I am not sure why.
This is the relevant code:

```
$filename = $count . "_" . $_POST['aor'] . "_" . date("Y-m-d\=h:i") . ".txt";
$fh = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($fh, $_POST['text']);
fclose($fh);
```

$_POST['aor'] is an string (usually "Answer" or "Response"). The files are empty and don't have the expected .txt extension. Why?

Comment: what is the op of $_POST['aor'] ?

Comment: What is that `\=` meant to express in the call to `date()`?

Comment: @aniketashtekar What do you mean?

Comment: How _exactly_ is the created file named?

Comment: @arkascha Just that there will be an = between the date and the time.

Comment: OK, then why the preceding ` \ ` before the `=`?

Comment: @arkascha 7_Answer_2016-06-22=01.txt for example.

Comment: No, that certainly is _not_ the exact file name, according to your own statement in the question...

Comment: @arkascha I thought I had to escape it. Doesn't seem so, but also doesn't fix my problem...

Comment: @arkascha Yes that would be the expected result. The result right now is just  7_Answer_2016-06-22=01

Comment: Sounds _very_ strange. Have a try logging the content of `$filename` for debugging purpose.

Comment: @arkascha I did output it using javascript and there it shows the full and correct filename.

Comment: Why on earth by javascript?!? That is server side code!

Comment: Apart from that: you code executes as expected for me, no issue there.

Comment: @arkascha Found my mistake. The development server runs on windows...

Comment: OK, I have next to no experience with MS-Windows like systems. One more reason not to use them :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The problem is Windows. It doesn't like ":" in the filename. 
Therefore changing

```
$filename = $count . "_" . $_POST['aor'] . "_" . date("Y-m-d\=h:i") . ".txt";
```

to

```
$filename = $count . "_" . $_POST['aor'] . "_" . date('Y-m-d=h-i') . ".txt";
```

works.

Answer (score -1):

```
$filename = $count . "_" . $_POST['aor'] . "_" . date('Y-m-d\=h:i') . ".txt";
$fh = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($fh, $_POST['text']);
fclose($fh);
```

> change your double quote inside date function

Comment: That didn't change anything?